# Placing finger on an open string makes clicky sound

Tags: electric-guitar

After some jamming, I noticed my guitar makes a clicky sound every time I place my finger on some open string (it can only be heard with an amp connected, maybe it's too soft for it to be heard unplugged). I first figured it was hitting itself with some fret, probably because of bad neck calibration, but it keeps clicking even if I touch it very gently and almost not move it at all. All I could find over the internet related to this is sounds that are produced while **lifting** the finger, not placing it...

Comment: What happens if you use your right hand to lightly touch some of the strings and keep it there, and then you touch and release different strings with your left? Does it still "click"? If it *doesn't* click when you do that, then it's probably a pop caused by completing a ground circuit with your body. That's normal. If it *does* click when you do that then I don't know what it is.

Comment: Agree that it's almost certainly a ground connection.   Either that or you're Magneto in disguise.

Comment: @ToddWilcox you seem to be right... I'd never have thought the strings were conductive (they obviously are tho) nor they would be connected to anything (that I still don't know where)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft probably the latter

Comment: @ToddWilcox oh! you're talking about static! so my only fix would be to have an antistatic bracelet or wear shoes?

Comment: No, it's not static. It's actually electromagnetic radiation from things like household electricity and radio stations creating electric currents in the guitar strings that are then dissipated through your body when you touch the strings. Again, this is normal. All guitarists experience this all the time.

Comment: @ToddWilcox if you want to, put it as an answer and i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some introductory facts:

- The strings of an electric guitar must conduct electricity. That's actually how they work. When the string vibrates over the pickup, a very small current flows in the strings at the same frequency that the string is vibrating. Then that current causes another current in the pickups, again at the same frequency, and the pickup current is amplified to make the sound you hear. If you put nylon strings (that don't conduct electricity) on an electric guitar, you won't hear anything when you play it.
- The strings of an electric guitar are grounded via the bridge. The bridge conducts electricity and inside the body of the guitar there should be a wire that connects the bridge to the ground - usually the casing of one of the pots. This is to reduce the effects of the strings basically acting like radio antennas.

So, with that in mind, here's what's happening:

- When you're not touching any of the grounded parts of the guitar (bridge, strings, jack plate, possibly other parts), the strings are basically radio antennas. They are picking up radio waves that are then picked up by the pickups and amplified. Usually these radio waves are fairly weak and most (but not all) of the current induced by the radio waves bleeds off to ground and is not amplified.
- When you touch any grounded part of the guitar, the current induced in the strings by the radio waves partly bleeds to ground and partly bleeds into your body. This dramatically reduces the amount of current that is left in the strings and picked up by the pickups. So touching a grounded part of the guitar reduces the (usually quiet) buzz that you get with an electric guitar.
- Right at the moment of touching it, you're basically closing a circuit. Usually when circuits close there's a very rapid change in the flow of current, and that change is so rapid that it sends a pulse through the relevant conductors. That pulse is picked up by the pickups and is amplified as a pop.

Comment: "*When the string vibrates over the pickup, a very small current flows in the strings at the same frequency that the string is vibrating.*" There's a magnetic field around the string, which induces a current in the pickup coil, but there's no current running through the string, afaik.

Comment: @YourUncleBob Where does the magnetic field around the string come from? It is created by the current in the string. A conductor moving through a magnetic field has a current induced in it. The initial magnetic field is generated by the magnetic pole pieces of the pickup. Then when the string moves through that field, a current is induced in the string.

Comment: As I understand it, the pole pieces, which are permanent magnets, have their magnetic field distorted by the moving strings. The movement of the magnetic field relative to the coil, induces a current in the coil. (As you say, touching the strings grounds them, so any current running through the strings would disappear via your body.) See e.g. https://reilandercustomguitar.com/guitar-pickups-work-part-1-basic-concept/

Comment: @YourUncleBob http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/genwir2.html EMF is definitely generated in the strings. I think the “changes the shape of the magnetic field” explanation is a simplification. *How* does a ferromagnetic object “change the shape” of a nearby magnetic field? Through mutual induction.

Comment: Well, I'm nitpicking, of course. But as I see it, any current generated in the string, and any properties that current might have, are a side effect that doesn't directly contribute to the sound. It's the fact that the pole pieces' magnetic field is distorted that produces the signal in the coil. That's why I thought that *a very small current flows in the strings at the same frequency* would be confusing to the reader, because it seems to suggest that the signal is produced in the string.

Comment: The current in the string is caused by the movement of the string past the magnet. I think that's why YUB is objecting to the original wording.  We don't want people to think that the string-current is causing the signal in the pickup.

Comment: Uncle Bob is right. “Strings...must conduct electricity. That's actually how they work” – this bit is not true. They work by way of being ferromagnetic (iron and/or nickel). Aluminium or bronze strings wouldn't work, whereas nylon strings with powdered ferrite would (albeit badly), despite being nonconductive. — Perhaps aluminium strings would have a bit of eddy current induced in them as well, but at least for the thin treble strings it would be completely insignificant – the cross-section is too small. There is no current induced _along_ the string, this can be seen by a symmetry argument.

Comment: To see that it's really the ferromagnetism that matters, try putting phosphor-bronze acoustic strings on an electric guitar. They give a much weaker signal, because only the steel core contributes.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Unfortunately, phosphor bronze is also a poor electrical conductor, so that’s not an isolated experiment. It’s possible that the current the strings does not contribute much to the final signal, but there is definitely current induced in the strings.

Comment: @ToddWilcox phosphor bronze isn't a poor conductor at all. 3.6×10⁻⁸ Ωm, that's not quite as good as copper or aluminium (2.6×10⁻⁸ Ωm), but it's actually almost a factor 5 better than steel (1.7×10⁻⁷ Ωm).